# Difference between FPU rounding and tie breaking

Tags: floating-point, rounding, fpu

What (if any) is the difference between the [rounding to integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer) and [tie-breaking modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking), described in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)? In the [IEEE-754-2008 standard](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=4610935), there is no such differentiation (although I only scanned it briefly). There is no such differentiation in x86 [FPU control word](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap1.htm#cword) either.

So is it possible to have an architecture that rounds integers differently than it breaks ties? Are there any such architectures used nowadays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounding to integer is rounding to integer.  There are several ways of doing it; the article lists five of them.  If you choose round-to-nearest, there will be ties (`0.5`), and you have to handle those ties using a tie-breaking rule.  There are several ways of doing that, too, and the article lists some of them.

Comment: Ok, but how do those relate to the IEEE implementation of floating-point? Are those implemented separately, or is the FPU always using the same strategy for both rounding and tie-breaking?

Comment: The x87 has round up, round down, truncate, and round-to-nearest-breaking-ties-using-round-to-even.

Comment: And ties away from zero (at least the 2008 version does).

Comment: This actually answers the question, although I had to read it like five times and sleep on it, to start making the right sense.

Comment: AFAIK rounding modes do not only apply to rounding to integer, they also apply to the rounding that must take place after a floating point operation, to round down the excess bits of an intermediate result to the precision allowed for the given type.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yes, that's why I wrote my own answer, which emphasizes that

Comment: No, it is not what you wrote in your answer. Your answer only treats rounding to integer, unless you mean "least significant represented decimal". Rounding is done in binary, not in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

I got it figured out after some more thinking. The **tie-breaking** rules will **only** apply **if round to nearest** is selected. Then they help to decide what to do if the result ends up in `0.5` (may be even a floating-point result, where the `.5` part is just after the least significant represented decimal).

So if the mode is one of round towards ±∞ (infinity) or towards zero, no tie-breaking occurs, ever.

Only if the mode is nearest, then there is additional choice of tie-breaking algorithms, which the Wikipedia article lists. The IEEE standard allows round to nearest, ties to nearest even or alternately ties away from zero.

I'll leave this Q&A around for whoever may find it useful.